# Inner Join with Single Row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two table 1). adv_master and 2). adv_img_master

I applied InnerJoin on this two tables but I faced following issue

Single advertise have muleiple photos so It return multiple Advertise with photo.

But I actually want single advertise with only one photo from adv_img_master table

```
SELECT * FROM adv_master as am 
                    JOIN adv_img_master aim ON am.id = aim.adv_id;
```

It return duplicate advertise with multiple images. I want unique advertise with any matched single image.

Comment: Use group by for it. It will fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate fix to your problem would be to use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT am.advertisement, aim.image
FROM adv_master am
INNER JOIN adv_img_master aim
    ON am.id = aim.adv_id
```

But if you reveal your data, there might an alternative to this which is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.

Comment: @TIm i think `SELECT DISTINCT am.advertisement, aim.image` this returns multiple entries for different `image` for same `advertisement`.And question is about single row for one advertisement.

Comment: @SagarGangwal You might be right, but we would need to see sample data to draw this conclusion.